# User input to find a word in a dictionary

Tags: string, dictionary, input, lua

I'm fairly new to programming and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction?

I'm trying to take the users input and use that to find that word in the dictionary e.g. If I type in "jeff" itll look in the dictionary and tell me "12" because `cluthaTable["jeff"] = "12";`

```
cluthaTable = {};
cluthaTable["jeff"] = "12";

local defaultField

local function textListener( event )

    if ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "submitted" ) then
        -- Output resulting text from "defaultField"
        --print( event.target.text )

        -- Saves the input as a var for looking up name
        local test = event.target.text
            print(test)
    end
end


-- Create text field
defaultField = native.newTextField( 150, 150, 180, 30 )
defaultField:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )
```

Comment: What's actually your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this yet?

```
local result = cluthaTable[event.target.text]
```

If such a key exists in the dictionary, it will save that key's value to the result variable. Otherwise, the result variable will be nil.